# h2 header has different color on mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile, colors, safari

I have built web site ([www.dubovik.org](http://www.dubovik.org) it's on russian, but it's not relevant to the issue) everything looks quite ok except on mobile Safari (on iphone and ipad). Only **one h2** (with phone numbers) has blue color instead of white (as other h2's).
This is html with problematic heading:

```
 <h2 class="heading" id="left">694-29-29 <br> 7-911-922-35-97</h2>
```

And css:

```
h2 {
    clear: both;
    color:#444444;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: Helvetica,  italic;

}

.heading {
    width: 650px;
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;      
    text-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    line-height: 1em;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 335px;
    left: 1.5%;
    z-index: 5;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;      
    text-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Tried everything (style it differently, give it different classes and id's and style them differently) - mobile Safari renders h2 heading with phone number in blue color.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you update with ***major*** things you've tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS automatically makes telephone numbers into links. You can stop it from doing that like this:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Or you can keep the number as a link and style it like this:

```
a[href^=tel]{
    color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Oh, finally! Thank you very much it worked! Probably I have to read more about developing for mobile safari.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
color: #fff !important;
```

Comment: Please support your answers by fact, not assumption. Also, read [answer].